# How to render json with Phoenix framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest, phoenix-framework

If use Rails framework with ajax request, this way in controller can send data back to front-end:

```
def get_posts
  @posts = Post.where(user_id: params[:user_id].to_i)
  if request.xhr?
    render :json => {
      :posts => @posts
    }
  end
end
```

Front-end can catch it:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "<%= get_post_path %>",
  data: {user_id: $("#user_id").val()},
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    alert(data.posts);
    //...
  }
```

Then in Phoenix framework, how to send data back to front-end?

I saw this guide from official docs:

> https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/views.html#rendering-json

It's method is using `render("page.json", %{page: page})` to send data but I don't want to create a json file.

So is it possible to send data back to front-end like Rails way?

Comment: why the `-1` without any comment? I think that is a fair question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. You have quite a few steps though...
First, your router needs to pipe the request so it accepts json. Something like this:

```
  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/api", TodoWithAuthWeb do
    pipe_through :api
  
    resources "/posts", PostController, except: [:new, :edit]
  end
```

Then your controller action should render a .json view as

```
render(conn, "show.json", post: post)
```

And this `show.json` view would be something like

```
  def render("show.json", %{post: post}) do
    %{data: render_one(post, PostView, "post.json")}
  end

  def render("post.json", %{post: post}) do
    %{id: post.id,
      title: post.title}
  end
```

Or something like that.
You could just use the phx tool to generate an entire resource for you tho... For exemple, generating an user/controller/views/etc

```
mix phx.gen.json Authentication User users email:string encrypted_password:string
```

Where `Authentication` is the "package" name

`User` is your model name on the codebase

`users` is your collection name on the db

and the others args are similar to the rails generators I guess

There are some guides on the web such as [Building a Trello copy with Phoenix and React](https://bigardone.dev/blog/2016/01/04/trello-tribute-with-phoenix-and-react-pt-1)

You can also check my simple todo-list phoenix repo on github so you can see the basics [TodoApp example](https://github.com/fskinner/todo_app) (its pretty dull tho)